# problem with maven

Tags: maven

i have download project from svn and try to deply it it will give me error like

```
dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique:
```

what should i do for that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, for the dependency `primefaces`, `<version>` information has been repeated in two `pom.xml` files.  Remove from one place.